# Laravel 5 database will not seed

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateFinanceAccountsTable extends Migration
{

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('finance_accounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('created_by')->index();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('finance_accounts');
    }

}
```

And the seeder:

```
class FinanceAccountsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('finance_accounts')->delete();

        App\Models\Finance\FinanceAccount::create([
            'name' => 'Default account',
            'created_by' => 1
        ]);
    }
}
```

Which is called via:

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{

    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();

        $this->call('UserRolesTableSeeder');
        $this->call('UserTableSeeder');
        $this->call('FinanceTransactionsTableSeeder');
        $this->call('FinanceAccountsTableSeeder');
        $this->call('CurrencyTableSeeder');
        $this->call('UserProfileTableSeeder');
    }
}
```

However, the table is created fine, but no data gets inserted.

The seeders for all my other tables work perfectly, just not for this one.

Does anyone have an idea why?

---

```
namespace App\Models\Finance;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class FinanceAccount extends Model {
    protected $table = 'finance_accounts';
}
```

Comment: Post your FinanceAccount class

Comment: Try to use the create method on some route just to make sure no exception is thrown.

Comment: @Gal I get:Argument 1 passed to App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::{closure}() must be an instance of Blueprint, instance of Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint given, called in C:\wamp\www\MBMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder.php on line 110 and defined

Comment: I meant the `FinanceAccount::create` not `Schema::create` also next time please provide the code you used as its impossible to know what your doing without it.